# MATLAB: GUI manipulation with timer wouldn't loop

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I was trying to create a seven segment display using gui manipulation using `TimerFcn`. I tried the following logic to loop the unit segment repeatedly. But MATLAB outputs the following error:

> Warning: You are deleting one or more running timer objects.  MATLAB has automatically stopped them before deletion.

And without deleting the timer it just goes non responsive.

```
while(true)
    y=timer('TimerFcn',@(~,~)set(handles.digit,'Visible','off','StartDelay',3);
    start(y)
    delete(y);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-explanatory. You never call `stop(y)` before calling `delete(y)`.

I'm not sure why you're using a timer at all here though, if all that you want is a 3 second delay, then use `pause`.

```
while true
    pause(3)    % wait 3 seconds
    set(handles.digit, 'Visible', 'off');
end
```